# Unable to hide a JButton when clicked.(JButton in a JTable)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, show-hide

I'm making a JTable n putting jbuttons in the `JTable`. I want to hide a button when it is clicked. but even after editing the code too much it is not happening, plz help.

```
IMAGE == https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkslfwho2lzdcqs/javadouuubt.png?dl=0
```

when i click on allow, it does some work on a database n should hide itself (but isn't hiding).

```
//Code for Table ==
String[] columns = {"username", "Phone", "ROOMS","Allow","Cancel"};
 //jt1 is the table name 
 String data2[][] =
            {{"John", "18", "Male","Allow","Cancel"},
              {"Daisy", "19", "Female","Allow","Cancel"},
              {"Dave", "23", "Male","Allow","Cancel"},
              {"Jake", "30", "Male","Allow","Cancel"}};

      jt1 = new JTable(data2, columns);
   jt1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 63));
     jt1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

     JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(jt1);

  //   jt1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());

 //following code will get the selected row
     ListSelectionModel model = jt1.getSelectionModel();

     model.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
     {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if(!model.isSelectionEmpty())
            {
            int selectedRow;


                if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting() )
                {   
                  selectedRow=model.getMinSelectionIndex();
                     Hotel_room_reservation_system.l=objacceptreq.rowreceived(selectedRow);//Hotel_room_reservation_system.l is a global variable declared 

                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Maybe this is going on");
        }


     });
 //following code will get the selected row .. Code was till here 2 get selected row



     jt1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) new ButtonRenderer2(jt1));;

//SET CUSTOM EDITOR TO TEAMS COLUMN
jt1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor2(new JTextField()));



//BUTTON RENDERER CLASS
class ButtonRenderer2  implements  TableCellRenderer {
    public JButton jbinside;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ButtonRenderer2(JTable jt1) {
        //SET BUTTON PROPERTIES
        jbinside =new JButton();
        jbinside.setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
                boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int col) {
        //SET PASSED OBJECT AS BUTTON TEXT
        jbinside.setText((obj==null) ? "":obj.toString());
        return jbinside;
    }

}

//BUTTON EDITOR CLASS
class ButtonEditor2 extends DefaultCellEditor {
    protected JButton btn;
    private String lbl;
    private Boolean clicked;

    public ButtonEditor2(JTextField txt) {
        super(txt);
        btn=new JButton();
        btn.setOpaque(true);

        //WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                acceptrequest obj2=new acceptrequest();
                obj2.accepthim(); //as i said the database sh*t
                fireEditingStopped();
                btn.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

     @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object obj,
            boolean selected, int row, int col) {
        //SET TEXT TO BUTTON,SET CLICKED TO TRUE,THEN RETURN THE BTN OBJECT
        lbl=(obj==null) ? "":obj.toString();
        btn.setText(lbl);
        clicked=true;
        return btn;
    }

    //IF BUTTON CELL VALUE CHNAGES,IF CLICKED THAT IS
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {

        if(clicked) {
            //SHOW US SOME MESSAGE
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn, " Granted permission");
            btn.setVisible(false);
        }
        //SET IT TO FALSE NOW THAT ITS CLICKED
        clicked=false;
        //return new String(lbl);
        return null;// doing so the text disapperas but not the button as allow is clicked
    }

     @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        //SET CLICKED TO FALSE FIRST
        clicked=false;
        btn.setVisible(false);
        //return super.stopCellEditing();
        return true;
    }

     @Override
    protected void fireEditingStopped() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.fireEditingStopped();
        //btn.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: no point of calling btn.setVisible(false); that button is already removed from the table once you called fireEditingStopped();  then table will draw the cell based on the render (button provided by the render will be paint in the cell)

Comment: i understand what u say .That is fy9 , but how ?? do i hide it when it has been clicked ?

Comment: you have a TableModel, then better to use your own type of objects to represent a single row or a cell, try to understand how editor return the user input ( refer getCellEditorValue() ), then JTable will call setValueAt method of the model. now based on the values in the model , your renderer should provide the presentation (button, or label with a text or empty label).

Comment: Hiding UI components does not provide a good user experience.

Comment: will bring it back,but tell me how 2 hide it or disable it anything is fine

Comment: I have updated the ode so plz tell me what part of the code i should maipulate with

Comment: I m a newbie so can't do it myself thnx

Comment: Even if u help me disable it it ill b fine